# carregar plugin datepicker em página chamada com ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Estou utilizando o plugin `datepicker`

Todos os meus input de datepicker, possui a classe chamada `datepicker`

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

Para assim, eu ter apenas uma configuração para o datepicker e poder utilizar em todas as páginas, então faço a configuração em um arquivo `dateconfig.js`, nesse arquivo eu possuo apenas o seguinte código:

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
    });
```

Mas eu tenho uma página com um `table` e nela existe o `input` com a `class="datepicker"`

Mas quando eu chamo uma modal via ajax, e nela existe também uma `input`, ela não carrega o plugin, então na página dessa modal eu copio o código de configuração e adiciono dentro de uma tag `<script>` //Codigo de configuração citado acima `</script>`, fazendo isso ele adiciona o plugin, mas lá na minha página com a `table`, ele duplica o `plugin`, criando 2 calendários do `datepicker`

Como eu poderia resolver esses dois problemas?

**Edit**

A forma que atualmente faço a chamada da modal é essa:

em meu "index/grid/table"

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modalContent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

a minha chamada de `ajax`, eu utilizei um `html helper` do `asp.net mvc`, mas acredito que ele se interprete como essa chamada do `jquery`:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "URL",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#modalContent").html(result);
            },
            complete: function (msg) {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Qual é o código que estás a usar para abrir o modal?

Comment: @Sergio editei a pergunta, é mais ou menos assim...

Comment: Ok, estou a sair agora do trabalho vou olhar mais logo aqui, mas porque não juntares `$("#modalContent .datepicker").datepicker({` dentro desse `complete: function (msg) {` do AJAX. Assim só vai juntar datepicker a esse(s) inputs que o modal tenha recebido.

Comment: @Sergio, mas toda requisição ajax, eu terei que fazer isso? torna-se o código de um simples "get" repetitivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu alteraria o ficheiro `dateconfig.js` para que o mesmo lide com o `datepicker` duma forma mais pragmática:

## Solução

```js
// Opções para o Datepicker
var options = {
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
    monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
};

// Controlo para instanciar e/ou apresentar o datepicker
$("body").on("click", ".datepicker", function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    if (!$this.hasClass("hasDatepicker")) {
        $this.datepicker(options);
    }

    $this.datepicker("show");
});
```

## Explicação

1. Estamos a delegar um evento ao elemento `body` que vai disparar sempre que se clicar num elemento com a classe `datepicker`.
2. O plugin *datepicker* ao criar uma instância, deixa nos elementos a classe de controlo `hasDatepicker`. Isto permite-nos verificar se o elemento que recebeu o clique já tem uma instância e assim passar logo para a apresentação do calendário.
3. Por fim, ao clicar nos elementos com a classe `datepicker` vamos abrir o mesmo.

Desta forma, seja de forma assíncrona, seja de forma "regular", todo o trabalho referente ao *datepicker* é realizado no teu ficheiro `dateconfig.js` e não precisas de tomar medidas adicionais para gerir o *plugin*.

## Exemplo

O exemplo em baixo encontra-se também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/L6py1jfk/).

```js
// Opções para o Datepicker
var options = {
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
    monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
};

// Controlo para instanciar e/ou apresentar o datepicker
$("body").on("click", ".datepicker", function(){
    
    var $this = $(this);
    
    if (!$this.hasClass("hasDatepicker")) {
        $this.datepicker(options);
    }
    
    $this.datepicker("show");
});


// Gerar elementos simulando chamada Ajax
$('button').on("click", function(){ $('body').append($('<input/>').addClass('datepicker'))});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="datepicker"> <button>+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você vai ter que aplicar o plugin somente nos elementos que tiverem sido carregados via AJAX para dentro do contêiner do modal:

```
$("#conteiner-do-modal .datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
    });
```

Estou assumindo que o contêiner do modal tenha o `id="conteiner-do-modal"`.

**Evitando repetições**

Para não ter erro em ficar repetindo, você pode criar um método que aplica o plugin usando um seletor jQuery, sendo que esta função ficará disponível globalmente para quem quiser chamar:

```
function setupDatepicker(seletor) {
    $(seletor).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
    });
}
```

Então em cada lugar que tiver que chamar, faça da forma que for apropriada:

- na página principal:

  ```
  setupDatepicker(".datepicker");
  ```
- após carregar o modal:

  ```
  setupDatepicker("#conteiner-do-modal .datepicker");
  ```

**O código acima em forma de plugin:**

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.setupDatepicker = function() {
        this.datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
            dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
            monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
        });
        return this;
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Para usar faça assim:

- na página principal:

  ```
  $(".datepicker").setupDatepicker();
  ```
- após carregar o modal:

  ```
  $("#conteiner-do-modal .datepicker").setupDatepicker();
  ```

Comment: Olá @Miguel Angelo, obrigado por responder, mas não há outra forma? fazendo isso parece tão repetitivo o código...

Comment: na verdade esse problema de não carregar, é praticamente em todos os plugins, rsrsrs =/

Comment: Editei a resposta com algo para evitar erros com repetição de código.

Comment: obrigado, imaginei que poderia fazer algo assim... Mas o arquivo com a função, deve ser passado na página que será carregada por ajax né? É que eu vejo que alguns plugins, nem precisam passar os arquivos dentro da página que está sendo carregada...

Comment: Não é necessário caso haja garantia que na página principal o arquivo já esteja carregado. Caso contrário, ai sim, precisará incluir o arquivo no carregamento do AJAX.

Comment: @Rod Uma opção legal seria criar um plugin, que faz o código acima... mas eu teria que ver como fazer um plugin pra jQuery pois eu nesse momento não sei.

Comment: Você pode repetir esse processo com os outros plugins... não acho que tenha outra forma melhor. Depois me diz ai o que achou. =)

Answer (score 0):

O problema aqui é que há conteudo a ser criado dinamicamente e seria necessário *delegar* o datepicker para nõ correr código duplicado e com isso gerar várias janelas de datepicker para cada input.

**Uma solução é** criar uma nova instancia cada vêz que novo conteúdo é adicionado ao DOM. O melhor é fazer isso na chamanda AJAX assim:

```
var formato = {
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
    monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
};

// ... depois dentro do ajax: 

complete: function (msg) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $("#conteiner-do-modal .datepicker").datepicker(formato);
}
```

e dessa maneira somente os novos inputs vão ser selecionados.

**Outra solução é** chamar o datepicker delegando num evento, por exemplo focusin:

```
$("body").on("input.datepicker", "focusin", function(){
   $(this).datepicker(formato);
});
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/6ajoomct/

Answer (score 0):

Pra começar, as configurações você pode setar utilizando a função [`setDefaults`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-setDefaults).

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});
```

Agora, para adicionar o datepicker apenas aos inputs com classe `datepicker` e que ainda não possuem o datepicker inicializado, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$(".datepicker:data(datepicker)").datepicker();
```

**Como funciona?** Os plugins do jquery ui sempre armazenam no elemento a instância do objeto criado, utilizando o nome do plugin (neste caso, `datepicker`). Assim, para verificar se o plugin já foi inicializado no elemento, é só verificar pela existência da instância no mesmo.

Uma versão final do seu código poderia ser a seguinte:

```
function iniciarDatepicker() {
    // você pode passar as configurações aqui ou setar via o setDefults
    $(".datepicker:data(datepicker)").datepicker();
}
```

Assim, você pode chamar sempre a mesma função.